# File Download using iframe not working in Iphone/Ipad

Tags: jquery, iphone, asp.net-mvc, iframe

File download feature is not working for my MVC-Bootstrap web application that uses an iframe in Iphones/Ipads ( for both Safari and Chrome). Everything works well in desktops,laptops and in Android devices ( for all browsers).

In a button click, I use the below Jquery code to invoke an iframe to download a PDF

```
 $("#iframedownload").attr("src", downloadURL);
```

downloadURL points to the page that has the code to download the file.

Code to download file

```
return File(filebyteArray, "application/pdf", string.Format("Myfile.pdf", 
DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
```

Iframe

```
<iframe id="iframedownload" style="display: none"></iframe>
```

Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like iframe download approach is not supported in Iphone/Ipad

Use  **window.location** instead

```
window.location = "@Url.Action(Action, Controller)";
```

Comment: Any sources for this info.