# Download "pdf" button not working on ipad/iphone

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have the following JS code, that makes users download a pdf file. This code works, except on Ipad and Iphone.

```
//s is the url to download
iso.downlURL = function(s)
{

  var iframe = document.getElementById("hiddenDownloader");
  if (iframe === null)
  {
    iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  
    iframe.id = "hiddenDownloader";
    iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  }
  iframe.src = s;

  return true;
};
```

I have found the following post, that might have had the same issue:

[File Download using iframe not working in Iphone/Ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340337/file-download-using-iframe-not-working-in-iphone-ipad)

But I am not sure what he is suggesting as the solution, how to change it?

-------------Update---------------------

I should probably mention that the issue with ipad and iphone, is that the download button is not clickable. It's just grey/disabled

Comment: It says to set `window.location = s` for iPhone/iPad

Comment: That issue is unrelated to the code you posted. Please put the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Then just ignore the code I posted that I say might be related. I have posted my code that causes the problem

Answer (score 0):

The attempts to display the PDF in a hidden iframe. On some systems that will act as a hack to cause it to be downloaded.

It won't work on iOS because Mobile Safari doesn't have any concept of "Downloading PDFs". The only way to download a PDF in Mobile Safari is to:

1. Open it in the browser normally
2. The user clicks the "Share this" button
3. The user picks an application (such as Good Reader) which will store the PDF in its storage area

If you want a reliable "Download a PDF" feature with a sensible fallover position for browsers which don't understand downloading, then use [the `Content-Disposition` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) and a regular link.